# repeating a function in R and pass values to a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, repeat

I am using an inbuilt  function from the `sde` package:

```
set.seed(123)
X <- sde.sim(model="OU", theta=c(3,1,2), N=10000, delta=1)
```

I want to repeat the same function 1000 times without changing any parameters, each time it will give a time series as output. I want to pass it to a matrix.

can anyone help me with the repeat command as its different from the normal repeat where you have a constraint.

Comment: You want to create 1K matrices in your global environment?

Comment: @Amy you want 1000 matrices or 1 matrix with 1000 rows ?

Comment: I guess the OP wants to store 1K time series and not exactly *matrices*.

Comment: Perhaps you can make use of `replicate` and store your 1k outputs in a single list. For example `replicate(3, expr = rnorm(2), simplify = FALSE)` or `replicate(3, expr = rnorm(2), simplify = TRUE)` to store the result in a matrix

Answer (score 1):

With what I understood I would go with a simple for loop

```
mat <- matrix(,1000,10001)
for (x in 1:1000) { mat[x,] <- sde.sim(model="OU", theta=c(3,1,2), N=10000, delta=1) }
```

---

Another option from @DavidArenburg comment:

```
mat <- matrix(sde.sim(model="OU", theta=c(3,1,2), N=(1e7 -1), delta=1),nrow=1e3,ncol=1e4)
```

We have to set N to row by col minus 1 to get a divisible value at end (so each row will be of 10 000 values exactly and not 10 001 as in the for loop.

**WARNING** Unlike the for loop, here each line will not start with 1, only the first entry will be 1.

Comment: Tensibai both your suggestions worked. mat <- matrix(sde.sim(model="OU", theta=c(3,1,2), N=(1e7 -1), delta=1),nrow=1e3,ncol=1e4) was faster.

Comment: @Amy Indeed, but the result are slightly different, if the first column has not to be 1 for each series the second form is better as it avoid the loop and multiple calls to sde.sim

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replicate` to run the function 1000 times and use `cbind` to combine the resulting time series into a matrix.

```
result = do.call( cbind, replicate(1000, sde.sim(model="OU", theta=c(3,1,2), N=10000, delta=1), simplify=FALSE ) )
```

Comment: Although this code segment might answer the question, one should add an explanation to it.